# Stuck while calling functions in a while loop?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

My program is supposed to record information for athletes in a race. When I select the option to add a score for an athlete, it calls the input_scores function, but then it won't get out of it? Also, for option "b", I want it to display the message that there's no record available if the list athlete_results is empty. I hope I've explained things ok, I am new to programming so any help is appreciated!

```
menu = """Choose an option:
'a' = Input score
'b' = Display results
'c' = quit
>
"""

athlete_results = []
choice = input(menu).strip().lower()


def input_scores():
    name = input("Name: ").strip().title()
    country = input("Country: ").strip().title()
    time = input("Time: ").strip()

    athlete_results.append({
        "Name": name,
        "Country": country,
        "Time:": time
    })


def display_results():
    for athlete in athlete_results:
        name, country, time = athlete_results.values
        print(f"{name}| {country}| {time}s")

while True:
    if choice == 'a':
        input_scores()
    elif choice == 'b':
        if athlete_results:
            display_results()
    elif choice == 'c':
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid option!!!")
```

Comment: move `choice = input(menu).strip().lower()` to a line directly after `while True` in order to have a chance to change the option or quit:.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the line

```
choice = input(menu).strip().lower()
```

to a line directly after while True:

```
while True:
    choice = input(menu).strip().lower()
```

in order to have a chance to change the option or quit.